# MySQL extremely simple date query is slow

Tags: mysql, sql

I've went over this many times but I couldnt find a way to make this faster. I have a table with about 4 million records and I want to grab rows from a specific date range (which would only yield about 10000 results). My query takes 10 seconds to execute... why!?

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  banjo_live.actions_activity
    where  userid IN (102,164,94,140)
      AND  actionsid=4
      AND  (actions_activity_timestamp between '2021-06-01 00:00:00'
                                           AND '2021-06-31 23:23:23')
      AND  new_statusid NOT IN (10,13)
    LIMIT  0, 50000
```

Surely this shouldnt take 10 seconds. What could be the issue?

Thanks

My table;

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `actions_activity`;
CREATE TABLE `actions_activity`  (
  `actions_activity_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `orderid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `barcodeid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `skuid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sku_code` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `actionsid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `action_note` text CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
  `starting_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `new_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `old_statusid` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Old Status',
  `new_statusid` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'New Status',
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Handled By',
  `actions_activity_timestamp` timestamp(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0),
  `actions_activity_created_at` timestamp(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `sessionid` int(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`actions_activity_id`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `FetchingIndex`(`barcodeid`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `skuindex`(`skuid`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `searchbysession`(`sessionid`) USING BTREE,
  FULLTEXT INDEX `sku_code`(`sku_code`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 4336767 CHARACTER SET = latin1 COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;
```

Comment: `Surely this shouldnt take 10 seconds.` Why do you think so? Is table small? Do you have indexes on all columns `userid`, `actions_activity_timestamp`, `new_statusid`?

Comment: I am afraid it comes time to read about indexes

Comment: How many rows is this returning?

Comment: A note on the indexes: if you have _separate_ indexes for each of the columns listed in the other comment, *only one of those indexes will be used*. You need _one index_ covering each of the appropriate columns, and the order the columns are listed in the index also matters (go from highest selectivity to lowest). I might just do one index like this: `(actionsid, userid, actions_activity_timestamp)`. New_statusid also matters, but they the time you check the others you may not have enough rows left to justify it's inclusion... but of course, always test for that kind of thing.

Comment: `LIMIT`ing without `ORDER`ing rarely makes sense.

Comment: did you mean `23:59:59` instead of `23:23:23`?

Answer (score 1):

- 23:23:23 ??  -- Gordon's rewrite avoids typos like this.  Or, I prefer this:

  ```
  actions_activity_timestamp >= '2021-06-01' AND
  actions_activity_timestamp  < '2021-06-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
  ```
- Add a 2-column index where the second column is whichever of the other things in the `WHERE` is most selective:

  ```
  INDEX(actionsid, ...)
  ```
- Once you add an `ORDER BY` (cf, The Impaler), there may be a better index.
- Are you really expecting 10K rows of output?  That will choke most clients.  Maybe there is some processing you could have SQL do so the output won't be as bulky?

Answer (score -1):

First, I assume you intend:

```
SELECT *
FROM banjo_live.actions_activity 
WHERE userid IN (102,164,94,140) AND
      actionsid = 4 AND
      actions_activity_timestamp >= '2021-06-01' AND
      actions_activity_timestamp < '2021-07-01' AND
      new_statusid NOT IN (10, 13)
LIMIT 0, 50000;
```

You want a composite index.  Without knowing the sizes of the fields, I would suggest an index on `(actionsid, userid, actions_activity_timestamp, new_statusid)`.